# I cancelled partition editor by mistake ,what to do now?

Tags: filesystems

I cancelled gparted operation by mistake .Now one of the partition became corrupted ,what to next? Should I format it? Data is important to me ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) *might* be able to help you.  The key word here is *might*.

> TestDisk can
>
> - Fix partition table, recover deleted partition
> - Recover FAT32 boot sector from its backup
> - Rebuild FAT12/FAT16/FAT32 boot sector
> - Fix FAT tables
> - Rebuild NTFS boot sector
> - Recover NTFS boot sector from its backup
> - Fix MFT using MFT mirror
> - Locate ext2/ext3/ext4 Backup SuperBlock
> - Undelete files from FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2 filesystem
> - Copy files from deleted FAT, exFAT, NTFS and ext2/ext3/ext4 partitions.

Find a LiveCD that contains TestDisk on their [LiveCD](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk_Livecd) page

Comment: Should I format that disk before proceed? Currently it shows unknown partition

Comment: I have not used TestDisk before but I would not carry on a format as it may make it harder to recover any data.  If you are wanting to restore the drive to its prior state to try and recover data then I would try Testdisk from a LiveCD without formatting first.  In theory TestDisk might be able to restore the partition(s).

Comment: do not format the disk!! boot your system with a livecd of sorts and run testdisk from there. Make sure the HD you want to recover is unmounted.

Comment: Thanks ,but test diskhelped me recover the partition ,but another partition disappeared